# Hiding a zero annotation on a Swift Charts donut chart

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftcharts

I have made a donut chart in Swift Charts. It can have 3 segments representing items in the user's data with problems (red), warnings (orange) or normal items (secondary / neutral colour).

Sometimes the segments might have a zero value, but I have noticed that the annotation still displays zero and it looks messy. I would like to hide this.

In this image, the zero annotation of the absent orange segment is circled in blue.

[image: Donnut chart with unwanted zero annotation highlighted in blue]

Here is my code:

```
Chart(data, id: \.category) { element in
    Plot {
        SectorMark(
            angle: .value("Count", element.count),
            // These settings make the red and orange sections more prominent
            innerRadius: .inset(element.category == .Nominal ? 32 : 40),
            outerRadius: .inset(element.category == .Nominal ? 8 : 0),
            angularInset: 2.0
        )
            .cornerRadius(4)
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Category", element.category.rawValue))
            // Here is the styling for the annotations
            .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                Text("\(element.count)")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.systemGroupedBackground.opacity(0.8))
            }
        }
            .accessibilityLabel(element.category.rawValue.capitalized)
            .accessibilityValue("\(element.count) items")
    }
        .chartForegroundStyleScale(
            domain: IssueCategory.allCases,
            range: [.red, .orange, .secondary.opacity(0.5)]
        )
        .chartPlotStyle { plotArea in
            plotArea
                .background(Color.clear)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        .accessibilityChartDescriptor(self)
        .chartXAxis(.visible)
        .chartXScale(domain: 0...drugs.count)
        .chartYScale(range: .plotDimension(endPadding: -8))
        .chartLegend(.hidden)
        .chartBackground { proxy in
            Text("\(drugs.count)")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
        }
            .frame(height: 196)
```

In summary, I'm hoping to hide the annotation (a number label in my case) if it is zero and thus it's segment is not being displayed.

Comment: Just wrap the `Text("\(element.count)")` with an `if element.count > 0 { ... }`?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks! Perhaps that should have been obvious to me but it wasn't! I have tested it and it works. Happy to upvote and accept an answer if you want to post it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.annotation` takes a `@ViewBuilder` closure, so you can just use an `if` statement:

```
.annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
    if element.count > 0 {
        Text("\(element.count)")
    }
}
```